# binding database to combobox and refreshing

Tags: sql, database, c++builder

I'd like to bind usernames from database to combobox. I tried it with query->datasource, just datasource, just dataset and dataset->datasource. All ways work perfectly to show usernames and choose them to item.text
But when i am adding a new user in other form with query method database is not refreshing and the new user is not represented in combobox. I tried refresh method of dataset, but it is not working at all. I tried synch with livebinding designer. Not working either.
Any suggestions?
[choosing user form presented on the pic with livebinding designer:

[image: img]

Comment: I am using `libMySQL.dll` for direct access to databases from C++ instead (no components) and then feed the VCL visual components by the results. Its a bit harder to start but you would have  full control on the behavior and avoid problems like you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem. 
I had to deactivate dataset and activate it again in certain forms.
Anyway thanks for answer ;)